# Detecting user's country and city

Tags: api, ip-geolocation

I am going to write some web application which should detect user's country and city. For example when user enters site web application should display information in his/her native language, it should say that his/her country (and city, I do not know whether it is possible or not). Do you know any database (IP database) or any other way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try http://www.netimpact.com/faq

Its free for 250 queries in 24 hours.

Or you can use simple javascript code, that negotiates with client's browser to detect exact latitude, and longitude.

```
// Check for geolocation support
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    // Use method getCurrentPosition to get coordinates
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
        // Access them accordingly
        alert(position.coords.latitude + ", " + position.coords.longitude);
    });
}
```

However, This requires user's permission to share his location.

Comment: This makes you dependent on a 3rd party which you will need to query every time. Using a local database with this info will make your application faster, more reliable and without limitations when it comes to the amount of queries :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use MaxMind's free GeoLite database.
There is examples and the database file for free download over at http://www.maxmind.com/app/geolitecity

I think it is updated about every month. Have been using it for years and no complaints!

Comment: I agree - MaxMind's free GeoLite is just what you need. But beware that you may get the wrong location for users on a corporate network (you'll get location of the corporate hub, not the user). This is true of all IP lookup solutions, not just MaxMind.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.hostip.info/ 
Hostip.info is a community-based project to geolocate IP addresses, making the database freely available (see below) but it needs you to put in your city to make it work.